# Add different class as per number of li tags

Tags: jquery, css

Requirement is, if I have more than two (li) tags then apply class "col_3" on ul tag otherwise it should be class "col_2"

Example:
**If two columns**

```
<div class="container">
   <ul class="col_2">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Example:
**If more than two columns**

```
<div class="container">
   <ul class="col_3">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
    <li>six</li>
    <li>seven</li>
    <li>eight</li>
    <li>nine</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: So what's the problem?check the length of li and then removeClass col_2 and addClass col_3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
if($('.container li').length>2){
   $('.container ul').addClass('col_3');
}else{
   $('.container ul').addClass('col_2');
}
```

Comment: we must also write the else part. As, we are unaware of the initialization class( whether it is col_2 or col_3).

Answer (score 1):

try this : iterate all ul and then apply class accordingly

```
//remove all classes first

$('.container ul').removeClass('col_2 col_3');

//iterate all container and apply class
$('.container').each(function(){
   if($(this).find('li').length >2)
     $(this).find('ul').addClass('col_3');
   else
     $(this).find('ul').addClass('col_2');
});
```